# Binomial Coefficients optimization

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

Given n and R, I have to find the minimum value of k such that:

$${(2^n)-1 \choose k}\bmod(2^n)==R$$

Where $k = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, 2^n-1\}$

Here ${n \choose k}$ is the binomial coefficient $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$
Here $n$ and $R$ have range of around 100 so that the calculations would involve bigint.

I have managed to calculate and check whether the remainder equals $R$ for the values of binomial coefficients using the previous values of binomial coefficients for a given $n$ by varying $k$ from $0$ to $2^\frac{n}{2}$ as the values of the binomial coefficients increase till the middle and then starts repeating.

I need to further optimize my solution in terms of speed. Can I further decrease my range of $k$? Or is there any theorem regarding binomial coefficients and remainder(modulo) operation that I can use to increase efficiency may be doing in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ or $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ time?

Example:

for n=1, R=0 output: -1 as there is no value of k can satisfy the relation.

for n=1, R=1 output: 0

for n=3, R=7 output: 1

for n=4, R=3 output: 7

Comment: You may be interested in [Lucas' theorem](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf).

Comment: @Shaktal: thanks for editing. I could you tell me how you did that?

Comment: Click "edit" and you will see the LaTeX code used to create the formatting (you can do this on any post on the site, I believe). By the way, if $R=2^n$, then using the letter $R$ I think is just superfluouos.

Comment: @Shaktal: isn't Lucas' theorem about remainder when divided by prime?

Comment: R isn't equal to 2^n. It is less than that.

Comment: The person who mentioned Lucas' theorem was me, not Shaktal. So $R$ is the remainder mod $2^n$ I take it? Please see equation (2) of the link I gave. Also note that the $p$-adic valuation of $m!$ can quickly be computed as $(m-s)/(p-1)$, where $s$ is the sum of the digits of $m$ in base-$p$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8235/discussion-between-amit-tiwari-and-anon)

Comment: I misunderstood the problem: you already have the remainder, and need to compute a minimal $k$.

Comment: You might consider using 128-bit integers `__int128` rather than bignum ([ref.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)).

Comment: @Douglas: yes I can use that but anyway using bignum won't be a problem. I only need to narrow down the computation. Please tell how can I further optimize my solution.